# The add on not showing up after I install it

Tags: add-on

Recently I met a question, where I created an Add-on, when I am testing it in the script field, it will show up after I have run this script. However, after that I save this .py file into my disk, and install it, it just doesn't show up.
[image]
[image]

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "moveY0001",
    "category": "Object",
}
import bpy

class ObjectMoveY0001(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My Object Moving Script"""      # Use this as a tooltip for menu items and buttons.
    bl_idname = "object.movey0001"        # Unique identifier for buttons and menu items to reference.
    bl_label = "move_Y_0001"         # Display name in the interface.
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}  # Enable undo for the operator.

    def execute(self, context):        # execute() is called when running the operator.
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0.0, 0.001, 0.0), orient_axis_ortho='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        print("hello")
        return {'FINISHED'}            # Lets Blender know the operator finished successfully.
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ObjectMoveY0001.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectMoveY0001)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)  # Adds the new operator to an existing menu.

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectMoveY0001)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

when enabling the addon, it seems that there is no info printed in the windows console:

```
Modules Installed (moveY0001) from 'F:\\Blender\\moveY0001.py' into 'C:\\Users\\aabb\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.0\\scripts\\addons'
```

Comment: Can you paste your python code as text in your question?  Also, can you check the Info window to see if there are any messages when you install and enable the addon version?  Finally, if you're on Windows, can you toggle the System Console (in the "Windows" menu) and see if there are any messages there when you install and enable?

Comment: Of course, I update these in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add required blender version to Meta Info block. Without you should get a warning in Preferences like 'Upgrade to 2.8x required'.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "moveY0001",
    "category": "Object",
    "blender": (3, 00, 0),   ## add
}
```

Some more information you can find here [Meta Info](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Addons/Guidelines/metainfo#blender)

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, this answer solved my problem exactly, thank you very much!